# proxmox проброс видео карты в виртуальную машину

Tags: linux, виртуальная-машина, видеокарта, proxmox

Доброго времени суток.

Пытался пробросить видео карту в виртуальную машину по статье (https://habr.com/ru/post/437598/), но не удачно.

При указании параметров конфига **/etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf** после перезагрузки система зависает. ( помогает только hardreset )

Если не прописать туда параметры видео карты, то загрузка проходит.
Более того в виртуальной машине я могу увидеть видео карту и даже могу попытаться поставить на неё драйвера, но потом будет BSOD ( то-ли не так версия драйвера то-ли видео карта не до конца проброшена ( скорее всего последнее ))

---

в BIOS активны vt-d опции и intel_iommu включен

```
root@pve:~# dmesg | grep IOM
[    0.039556] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
```

На сколько понял на материнской плате и у процессора есть возможность проброса, но не уверен есть ли она у самой видео карты. ( не понял как проверить , буду рад если подскажите )

---

Характеристики: 
**OS:** proxmox  6.3-2 ( debian 10 ) 
**CPU:** [Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2628 v3](https://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-ASUS/GeForce_GT630_1GB_DDR3_-_GT630-SL-1GD3-L.html)  
**MB:** QIYIDA X99-H9 
**RAM:** 8GB

тестируемые видео карты:

- [ASUS GeForce® GT 630 1 Гб GDDR5 (GT630-1GD5)](https://www.gpuzoo.com/GPU-ASUS/GeForce_GT630_1GB_DDR3_-_GT630-SL-1GD3-L.html)
- [nVidia GeForce GT1030 MSI 2Gb](https://ru.msi.com/Graphics-Card/GeForce-GT-1030-2G-LP-OC.html)

Можете подсказать в чем проблема или подсказать направление для решения ?
Или данные видеокарты не поддерживают возможность проброса в виртуалки?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Решение

Нашел решение ) , как оказалось все было достаточно глупо.

  Не знаю на что я рассчитывал, но прокидывать единственную видеокарту в системе, наверное было не лучшей идеей) скорее всего у меня из-за этого зависало при старте Debian.

Я купил себе еще одну дешевую видео карту и т.к. на моей материнской плате отсутствовал второй слот купил еще и расширение ( за 300р ) для подключения второй видиокарты. 

  В райзер я подключил видео карту которую я буду пробрасывать в виртуалку, а в слот видео карты на метеринке воткнул дешевую видео карту в качестве затычки. 

После через web proxmox добавил видео карту в виртуалку, уже в самой виртуалке доставил драйвера  и поставил галочку Primiry GPU. 
Все видео карта успешно проброшена.

Проброс успешно удался, в качестве теста запустил Portal 2 через steam link, все ок без проседаний.

В самом низу прикрепил фото с помощью чего я подключил вторую видео-карту.

Итоговые конфиги:
`/etc/pve/qemu-server/350.conf` - конфиг машин

```
boot: order=ide2;sata0
cores: 4
hostpci0: 05:00,x-vga=1
.....
machine: q35
memory: 6144
name: w
net0: virtio=36:1E:19:D2:FB:17,bridge=vmbr0,firewall=1
numa: 0
ostype: win7
sata0: SSD:350/vm-350-disk-0.qcow2,size=32G
scsihw: virtio-scsi-pci
smbios1: uuid=637d5e8a-3380-49a8-afaa-c6bf6cd10bc0
sockets: 1
usb0: host=1c4f:0002,usb3=1
vmgenid: 6c562471-0d88-4134-b7c1-f53c6fc8a246
```

`/etc/pve/qemu-server/vmid.conf`

```
hostpci0: 05:00
```

`/etc/modprobe.d/vfio.conf` - id устройства видео карты

```
options vfio-pci ids=10de:0f00,10de:0bea
```

`/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

```
blacklist radeon
blacklist nouveau
blacklist nvidia
```

`/etc/default/grub`

```
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet intel_iommu=on"
...
```

фото платы-расширения для подключения второй видео-карты ( райзер для видео карты )

[image: райзер для видео карты]